# Yosemite upgrade–continuous slow screen redraw

Tags: macos, graphics, gpu

I recently upgraded to Yosemite, and now my laptop has the following issue:

Each and every window (the AppStore, Chrome, etc) seems to be continuously and very slowly redrawn, to the point where I can see the screen go white, and then slowly be drawn back in from the bottom to the top.

The only time when I every encountered a similar issue was when, on Ubuntu, I upgraded and lost support for my graphics card. However, I have no idea how to navigate this issue on OS X.

Comment: Mac spec would be useful, together with at least an Activity Monitor Memory usage picture.

Comment: Also, a system diagnosis next time it happens. Press shift+control+option+command+period and then wait at least 10 minutes (possibly three times as long if the system is wedged/swapping/slow to run code) before powering it off forcefully if need be. Lastly, can you make this happen or is it a one time / once a month thing?

Comment: Is it just Internet apps ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 I had the same problem and it was on every single app. From settings to chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem and I solved it by [resetting the PRAM/NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063), which is done via:

1. Shut down your Mac.
2. Locate the following keys on the keyboard: Command (⌘), Option, P, and R.
3. Turn on your Mac.
4. Press and hold the Command-Option-P-R keys immediately after you hear the startup sound.
5. Hold these keys until the computer restarts and you hear the startup sound for a second time.
6. Release the keys.

Comment: It's been a while, so I can no longer confirm that this would've solved my problem. I'll accept your answer nonetheless, though.